# How to use setPoolLimit to manage the connections?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm building an application by using golang with mongodb atlas which has a max connections. I tried to use "session.SetPoolLimit(5)" to ensure that there is no more than 5 connections at the same time. However, it did not work.

```
var originSession *mgo.Session
func query(wg *sync.WaitGroup)  {
    mySession := originSession.Copy()
    var items []interface{}
    mySession.DB("testdb").C("test").Find(nil).All(&items)
    time.Sleep(1500)
    mySession.Close()
    wg.Done()
}
func main() {
    originSession, _ = mgo.Dial(connectString) // connect to server
    defer originSession.Close()
    originSession.SetPoolLimit(5)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i:=0; i<50;i++{
        wg.Add(1)
          go getInfoBackWithSleep(&wg)
        }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I used db.serverStatus().connections to check the number of connections.

{ "current" : 1, "available" : 99, "totalCreated" : xxx}

{ "current" : 50, "available" : 50, "totalCreated" : xxx}

{ "current" : 1, "available" : 99, "totalCreated" : xxx}

To my understanding, the setPoolLimit(5) should keep the "current" not more than (1+5)=6. But it did not block other sessions that comes behind the first 5 sessions.

However, If I change the limit to 1. (setPoolLimit(1))  It would only let one single connection work at the same time while block others. Seems the pool limit only work if I set it as 1.